# Set of jQuery .onclick functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hiding and fading in different content on the same page using jQuery to `hide()` and `fadeIn()` the content depending on which link is clicked.

It works how I want it to, but the way I've written the jQuery looks like it could be simplified.

```
$("#navItem1").on('click', function(){
    $('#content-wrap1').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').hide();
    $('#content-wrap3').hide();
    $('#content-wrap4').hide();
    $('#content-wrap5').hide();
    $('#content-wrap1').fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#navItem2").on('click', function(){
    $('#content-wrap1').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').hide();
    $('#content-wrap3').hide();
    $('#content-wrap4').hide();
    $('#content-wrap5').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#navItem3").on('click', function(){
    $('#content-wrap1').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').hide();
    $('#content-wrap3').hide();
    $('#content-wrap4').hide();
    $('#content-wrap5').hide();
    $('#content-wrap3').fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#navItem4").on('click', function(){
    $('#content-wrap1').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').hide();
    $('#content-wrap3').hide();
    $('#content-wrap4').hide();
    $('#content-wrap5').hide();
    $('#content-wrap4').fadeIn(1000);
});
$("#navItem5").on('click', function(){
    $('#content-wrap1').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').hide();
    $('#content-wrap3').hide();
    $('#content-wrap4').hide();
    $('#content-wrap5').hide();
    $('#content-wrap5').fadeIn(1000);
});


function fadeInFirstContent(){
    $('#content-wrap1').fadeIn(1000);

}
fadeInFirstContent();
```

[Here's a jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQtwa/)

How can I rewrite the jQuery so it does exactly the same thing but in much less code?

Comment: For some reason all the current answers seem to want you to change the HTML or add random loops. There is no need. My answer here uses basic jQuery functionality to achieve all of this in just 5 lines: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/26236/24039. You'll benefit from the official jQuery interactive tutorial: http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, the HTML *should* be changed to use classes instead of these repetitive `[id]`s. It makes the HTML more expressive of the fact that these elements obviously share a similar class.

Comment: While @crm might be constrained and isn't in a position to update the HTML, I agree with zzzzBov that it's the best direction to take.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Perhaps change the HTML:

Navitem:

```
<span class="navItem" data-content-id="1"></span>
```

The content

```
<div id="content-wrap1" class="content-wrap"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.navItem').on('click',function(){
   $('.content-wrap').hide();
   $('#content-wrap'+$(this).data('content-id')).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: This is much better than using a substring of the ID. Also, you’re missing a `.` in front of `navItem`…

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, though I feel it would be cleaner with data attributes on the content-wrap elements instead of an ID. A selector like `.content-wrap[data-wrapid=VAR]` wouldn't be noticeably slower. Alternatively, simply use `eq()` to select the nth element.

Answer (score 13):

**You don't have to change the HTML markup at all.** You can make use of the starts-with [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) (`^=`):

```
// All elements with an ID starting with navItem...
$('[id^="navItem"]').on('click', function() {
    var
        // Get the ID as a string
        id = this.id,
        // Get the last character from the ID
        num = id.charAt(id.length-1)
    ;
    // Hide all elements with an ID starting with content-wrap...
    $('[id^="content-wrap"]').hide();
    // Fade in the relevant ID
    $('#content-wrap'+num).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

If we assume "navItem5" is used, here is what the variables would contain:

```
id == "navItem5"
num == "5"
$('#content-wrap'+num) == "#content-wrap5"
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hsDLE/2/).

This is very basic jQuery. You'd benefit from going through the official jQuery interactive tutorial: http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: Why not just do: `var id = this.id;`? No need for `$(this).attr('id')`... It's also massively faster.

Comment: That would be a simple oversight, I've modified the answer. :)

Comment: Possibly include `.toggle()` if OP is going to use the same click to show/fadeout.

Comment: While this answer works, it's very hacky to extract numbers out of ID attributes.

Comment: I’ll comment on my downvote from a few hours ago: this is incredibly fragile, and wanton abuse of IDs. What if the numbers go past `9`, for example? Why not just use a clean and very efficient class? *Why don't you cache that collection, or put it in an array, or something nice?*

Answer (score 5):

I think this should do the trick

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {  
    (function(i){
        $("#navItem" + i).on('click', function(){
            $('#content-wrap1').hide();
            $('#content-wrap2').hide();
            $('#content-wrap3').hide();
            $('#content-wrap4').hide();
            $('#content-wrap5').hide();
            $('#content-wrap' + i).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    })(j);
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what is happening in that for loop?

Comment: @crm: inside the loop I'm defining a function that gets a number as parameter. Inmediatly after defining the function, I'm calling it trough this statement `(j)`. This is a closure.

Comment: How does `i` hold the value? Shouldn't you be calling `j` within the loop? also why is `j` in the parenthesis at the end like that?

Comment: @crm: it's the magic of closures :) Here you have a SO popular question that may clarify this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work. `j` in the parenthesis at the end is the way to call the function I just defined with parameter `j`

Answer (score 3):

yes there is...there are many ways to simplify this.. i am doing it by using `data` attribute  to your `<a>` tag...and adding same class to all the contents `<div>` .(i am using content here)...

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<!-- Start of side menu -->
<ul id="mainNav">
    <li class="mainNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem1" data-content="content-wrap1">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mainNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem2" data-content="content-wrap2">Prices</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mainNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem3" data-content="content-wrap3">Find us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mainNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem4" data-content="content-wrap4">Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mainNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem5" data-content="content-wrap5">Gallery</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<!-- closes mainNav -->
<div id="content-wrap1" class="content">Home</div>
<div id="content-wrap2" class="content">Prices contents</div>
<div id="content-wrap3" class="content">find us contents</div>
<div id="content-wrap4" class="content">review contents</div>
<div id="content-wrap5" class="content">gallery contents</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('ul#mainNav li a').click(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('content')).fadeIn(1000);
});



function fadeInFirstContent() {
    $('#content-wrap1').fadeIn(1000);

}
fadeInFirstContent();
```

or without adding classes to content..

```
 $(function(){
   $('ul#mainNav li a').click(function () {
     $('div[id^="content-wrap"]').hide();
     $('#' + $(this).data('content')).fadeIn(1000);
  });
   $('#content-wrap1').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/VQtwa/1/)

Answer (score 2):

It could be done much shorter:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ADyp/

```
function hideAll(){
    $('#content-wrap1').hide();
    $('#content-wrap2').hide();
$('#content-wrap3').hide();
$('#content-wrap4').hide();
$('#content-wrap5').hide();
}

function showSelected(e){
    hideAll();
    $(e.target.hash).fadeIn(100);
}

$("#mainNav").find("a").each(function(i,o){ 
    $(o).click(showSelected);
});
```

Comment: `hideAll()` can be minimized to `$('#content-wrap1,#content-wrap2,#content-wrap3,#content-wrap4,#content-wrap5').hide()`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using an expressive structure such as:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#content-wrap1" id="navItem1" class="navItem">One</a>
    <a href="#content-wrap2" id="navItem2" class="navItem">Two</a>
    <a href="#content-wrap3" id="navItem3" class="navItem">Three</a>
</nav>
<div id="content-wrap1" class="content-wrap">...</div>
<div id="content-wrap2" class="content-wrap">...</div>
<div id="content-wrap3" class="content-wrap">...</div>
```

You can then toggle the display of the `content-wrap` items in a short, expressive manner.

```
$('.navItem').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.content-wrap').hide();
    $($(this).prop('hash')).fadeIn(1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This *does* suggest changing the HTML, but only in ways that make the content semantic.

Comment: You should make use of the [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attribute to store data, not the `href` attribute (`<a data-id="#content-wrap1" .../>` then you can pull it using `$(this).data('id')`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, the `href` is more appropriate if the item being clicked on is a link. The fragment identifier is designed to point the user to a particular ID in the DOM, so even if JavaScript is disabled, the same section will be highlighted. If the item is *not* a link, it certainly makes sense to use a `[data-*]` attribute, although I'd probably use `data-target` or `data-content-element` because `data-id` seems a little too ambiguous.

Comment: if JavaScript was disabled the element wouldn't be visible anyway, so it wouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, "the element wouldn't be visible anyway" no, if you set up your styles and scripts correctly, all the elements will be shown with javascript disabled. While it may not be what OP has set up, you have to remember that this *is* [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with minimal changes to the HTML (only a common container for the contents):

```
$( '.mainNavItem a' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#content > div' ).hide()  // hide all content divs 
                                  // (immediate div children of the main container)
        .eq( $( this ).parent().index() )  // match the index of the clicked link
                                           // with the index of the corresponding content
        .fadeIn( 1000 );          // display that div
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VQtwa/2/

Answer (score 1):

why not skip the javascript completely?

http://jsfiddle.net/zCd9g/

EDIT: sorry that's completely unhelpful seeing as this is a javascript question. Here's a solution with *some* modifications to the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/aECMb/

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $con = $('#main-content'),
        tar = $(this).data('show');

    $con.find('.contents').fadeOut();
    $con.find(tar).fadeIn();

});
```

Comment: It is ok to post a working demo on JSFiddle. Nevertheless, add the relevant code to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've noted some details, let me explain:

---

1. [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). jQuery allows you to use them too:

   `$("[id^='content-wrap']")` --> will select all elements which id starts with 'content-wrap'

---

2. [Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is an available method of JavaScript:

```
var number = "navItem15".substring(7);
// will return what is after position 7.. 
// resulting the number "15"
```

---

3. To start your menu with the first position. [This is](http://jsfiddle.net/VQtwa/22/) the best way:

```
(function(){
    $("#navItem1").trigger("click");
})();
// using this approach, you won't need copy your code into a function as you did
// this approach triggers the "click" event in the first menu automatically
```

---

Well, hope you got it!

Nice coding!